# How to add code to the layout through the WordPress admin panel?

Tags: wordpress

How to add code to the layout in right place through the WordPress admin panel?

[WordPress admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beu8Y.png)

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNjX0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using the WordPress Text Editor, for more inforamtion see here:

https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/text-editor/

Comment: you don't understand, which function take code from text edit and paste in right place to my layout template? <?php the_content(); ?> doesn't match